# How to "pack" an Ember CLI component?

Tags: ember-cli, reusability, ember-components

I'm using ember-cli and I made a custom component using ember-cli syntax & naming conventions. This is a highly reusable component and I'd like to know what is the better way to put it all into a "package" so it's easy to integrate into other projects.

My component use a `.js` file for the `Ember.Component` subclass along with a `.hbs` file for the template and yet another couple of `.js` files for the necessary `Ember.View` subclasses. Right now, every file is in its respective folder along with the files for the rest of my project.

How can I isolate the files related to the component and package them for reuse? In Ruby on Rails I use gems for this matter, and in jQuery I used to write plugins by extending `$.fn` in a single file.

Comment: If it something you want to use on different Ember apps, you may want to consider writing an addon: https://gist.github.com/kristianmandrup/ae3174217f68a6a51ed5

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of Ember CLI addon system. It's been designed for cases like this one. The process should be easy if you are familiar with Ember CLI already. As Ember CLI addon system's been reworked in the recent past and it's API was changing it's possible that older articles or guides on this topic became out of sync.

The most comprehensive and kept in sync guide on this topic is kristianmandrup's gist [Converting libraries to Ember CLI addons](https://gist.github.com/kristianmandrup/ae3174217f68a6a51ed5).

There is also an [Addons tutorials](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#addons) section on the official Ember CLI site.